# No funciona el preventDefault con keydown

Tags: javascript

tengo un input con un type fecha y lo que quiero lograr es que solo se permita ingresar la fecha por el calendario que trae el navegador para este tipo de input y no que sea modificable con los números del teclado ni las flechas. Este es mi código pero no quiere funcionar el preventDefault, ¿Alguna sugerencia?

**Se presenta este error en firefox.**

HTML (Es una modal):

```
<div class="modal-body">
        <form id="formulario_modal_finalizar_solicitud" method="POST">

          <!-- Content form -->
          <div class="row" id="form_labels_modal_finalizar_solicitud"></div>
          <!-- /Content form -->

          <!-- Content form -->
          <div class="row" id="form_inputs_modal_finalizar_solicitud">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-left f-s-14" id="div_dtm_fecha_finalizar">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-label font-weight-bold">Fecha finalizar <i class="fas fa-asterisk fa-xs text-danger"></i>
                
                </label>
              <input type="date" class="form-control input-lg f-s-14" name="dtm_fecha_finalizar" id="dtm_fecha_finalizar" value="" tabindex="1" max="2024-02-13">
              </div>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  /* --- Valida fecha inicial solicitud, gestionar solicitud y finalizar solicitud de un proceso  --- */
  if (e.target.id === 'dtm_fecha_iniciar' || e.target.id === 'dtm_fecha_iniciar_editar' || e.target.id === 'dtm_fecha_finalizar' || e.target.id === 'dtm_fecha_gestion') {
    const id = e.target.id

    //Aqui tengo otras validaciones por eso es necesario el primer evento click (uso la constante id), no los muestro para no alargar el código

    const inputFecha = document.getElementById(id)

    inputFecha.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
      if (event.key === 'ArrowUp' || event.key === 'ArrowDown' || (event.key >= '0' && event.key <= '9')) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML

Comment: Si quieres evitar el ' keydown' porqué lo filtras? basta con hacer la función: `input.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => e.preventDefault());` eso evita cualquier `keydown` o es que buscas un keydown específico?

Comment: @MauricioContreras si tienes razón gracias por tu aporte, aunque no se por que no logra funcionar el preventDefault en firefox.

Comment: ***Desde Firefox 65, los eventos `keydown` y `keyup` ahora se activan durante la composición del IME, para mejorar la compatibilidad entre navegadores para los usuarios de CJKT (error 354358 en Firefox)***. [Evento KeyDown](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event)

Comment: Parece que no es algo que puedas corregir de forma sencilla en Firefox.

Comment: Confirmo que no funciona en Firefox. La verdadera pregunta es: ¿por qué querrías romper la accesibilidad? ¿Y si el usuario se maneja mejor con el teclado que con el mouse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una solución rápida

```html
<input type="date" onkeydown="return false;" />
<input type="datetime-local" onkeydown="return false;" />
```

Comment: No funciono de esta forma amigo, lo realice así: 

<input type="date" class="form-control input-lg f-s-14" name="dtm_fecha_finalizar" id="dtm_fecha_finalizar" value="" tabindex="1" onkeydown="return false" max="2024-02-13">

Comment: @JuanRincon qué es lo que no funciona? La respuesta que te han dado evita el uso del teclado en los componentes de fecha y sólo permite la interacción con el mouse.

Comment: @MauricioContreras el código sigue permitiendo las entrada del teclado como flechas y números, intenta comprobarlo con el ejecutar de stackoverflow.

Comment: @JuanRincon Pues lo ejecuto y no me lo permite, entonces será un tema de navegador. Uso Brave browser. Qué navegador estás usando? Aclara tu pregunta con esos detalles.

Comment: @MauricioContreras tienes razón en chrome funciona pero uso firefox como principal y ahí es donde falla.

Comment: firefox funciona diferente y particularmente para type="date", estos son especiales cada navegador los hace diferente. En este aspecto no te puedo ayudar, parece funcionar en todos los chrome based pero no firefox no y creo que no hay forma de hacerlo funcionar.